# Double quotes are not copied normally. How can I edit them?

Tags: php, wordpress

When I copy the words with double quotes, .php pages show an error. Double quotes don't get copied normally. How can I solve it? Which codes can I edit? (My script is Wordpress.)

Example: `$goster = getenv(“HTTP_USER_AGENT”);`

Before HTTP and after AGENT double quotes in example above. It is a problem with my users. I think I must edit in blockquotes function in Wordpress. Any idea?

Comment: When I copy $goster = getenv(“HTTP_USER_AGENT”); as you see double quotes looks like ” but it has to be ".       ” --> "

Comment: ı m copying from web site to .php file in my desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Those are *smart quotes* (`e2 80 9c`), and aren't considered string delimiters by the PHP lexer, which it seems you already know.

Replace them with either the single quote `'` or double quotes `"`. If you are copying those from a program which is replacing normal quotes with smart quotes, it's definitely not designed for code and you should stop using it for that purpose.

Comment: yeah. but ı m losing my users for this error. how can ı show it normal double quotes? """" like them.