# PDO parse error unexpected ":"

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to establish a new PDO instance with the following code

```
<?php
$handler = new PDO(“mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=database”,
“root”, “”);
```

I get the following error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ')' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/example/connection.php on line 2

There has been no problems like this before until I attempted to do this on a new Mac. Can someone help with this issue?

Comment: all of those curly quotes need to be straightened `“` should be `"`

Comment: Looks like you're not typing in a proper editor. You shouldn't type in standard programs like Word or the likes, they aren't suitable for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Double quotes are not copied normally. How can I edit them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303353/double-quotes-are-not-copied-normally-how-can-i-edit-them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$handler = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=database",
"root", "");
```

your quotes were wrong

Answer (score 0):

You should to this:

```
<?php
$handler = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=database","root", "");
```